# Passing array between php and jquery back and forth

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am making a notification system in which I get the row numbers of the user from the table whose new notifications just came in. 
I wanna save those row number in an array and pass it to the jquery which called the php to get the row numbers... it works perfect now i wanna pass that json returned object with all the array values to a different php page which will get the values from that array one by one and perform some action on each value.... 
How can i do that ? I have searched quite a lot but found nothing that meets the requirement. 
Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $last_id = json_decode($_POST['arr'],true);
$size = sizeof($last_id);
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)

{

   $element = $last_id[$i];
    $reply = mysql_query("select * from user_messages where id = '$element'");

        while($new_message = mysql_fetch_array($reply))
        {
            echo'
                    <div class="incomming_msg_wrapper">
                        <p class="incomming_msg">'.$new_message['message'].'</p>
                    </div> <br>
            ';
        }
}
```

**Thats how I got it working and it works fine. All I wanted to do is to access the elements of the json type array send to php via jquery by $.post() function one by one  **

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you have a JSON Object in Javascript/JQuery and you want to send that to PHP via Ajax again. Then why don't you do it like this:

In Javascript:

```
function sendJSONToPHPAgain(jsonData)
    $.ajax({
        url: 'endpoint.php',
        data: {
            json: JSON.stringify(jsonData)
        },
        contentType: "application/json",
    });
}
```

In PHP (endpoint.php):

```
$json = json_decode($_REQUEST['json'], $assoc=true);
// now you have a nice php array to work with ...
```

For example, use it like that:

```
var d = {a:2, b:3, c:"Hello World"};
sendJSONToPHPAgain(d);
```

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

i've found two "gists" tha may help you out: [Convert array php to js array](https://gist.github.com/jruzafa/5335365) and [Convert json to php code](https://gist.github.com/gingermusketeer/6638728)